# Groovy error No signature of method: java.lang.String.call()

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-groovy

Trying to resolve this in the pipeline script, the loop is working but somehow the script is throwing an error at the time of executing shell for each parameter value which is the nodename. The error is

```
first database
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [$node, org.jenkinsci.plugins.wor
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), trim(), size(), next(), grep()
```

The script :

```
node {
    properties([
    parameters([

booleanParam(name: 'first database', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,
booleanParam(name: 'second database', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,

    ])
])

    stage('Stash') { 
       def list = []
       if("${params['first database']}" == "true") {
           list.add("first database")
       }
       if("${params['second database']}" == "true") {
           list.add("second database")
       }

       list.each { node ->
            echo "$node"
             node('$node') {

     sh """
 echo -e "Hostname:\t\t"`hostname`'

"""

             }
           
            }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop variable seems to be conflicting with the `node(){}` directive. Change the variable name from `node` to something else. Refer the following.

```
list.each { nodeName ->
    echo "$nodeName"
    node(nodeName) {
        sh """
          echo -e "Hostname:\t\t"`hostname`'
         """
    }
}
```